# Selenium Webdriver element identification

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hi I am new to `Selenium Webdriver`.

I have taken this [website](http://www.stepintohealth.qa) and I am trying to click on the Register Link. I have written the following code.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.stepintohealth.qa");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Register")).click();
```

while executing the code it is throwing element not found exception. i have tried same in `seleniunm IDE` it works without any issue. I have verified for the `iframes` also, but Register link is not in `iframes`.

Comment: What language is this? Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the world of `Selenium`. It is often the element wait/find issue that you are facing. I added [explicit](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) wait to make sure the element is there before you perform the click.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.stepintohealth.qa");

By byCss = By.cssSelector(".right1.navmenu a.register");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byCss ));
myDynamicElement.click();
```

Couple of things to keep in mind:

1. You don't want to mix the implicit and explicit waits together since that can be a performance issue. It is not recommended.
2. Selector is very important in finding the element uniquely. I tend to avoid `LinkText` as much as I can. `id` should be your first choice always. Try using `name`,`clasName`,`cssSelector`,`xpath` if you can. In this case className did not work pretty good. Tested with `cssSelector` and did what it supposed to do. See [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#locating-ui-elements-webelements) for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. i just had to change the waiting time to 30 sec.

Comment: I would really want to know why I am getting downvote for this answer. Please leave a comment and give me the chance of improvement.